# Cloudera manager Page isn't opening

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudera

I Followed these steps :

First i took a server(Cent OS 6) from Google Cloud in Asia South reagion.
and Executed these commands :

1. sudo -i
2. chkconfig iptables off
3. service iptables stop
4. setenforce 0
5. vi /etc/selinux/config (SELINUX=disabled)
6. init 6
7. wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/installer/latest/cloudera-manager-installer.bin
8. chmod u+x cloudera-manager-installer.bin
9. sudo ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin

Done! Cloudera manager installed Successfully.

But when I am trying to access http://my_public_ip:7180/ then getting timed out error.

ALso i waited for 1 hour after installing cloudera(for startup settings). but again same response.

Comment: Will have seen: [cloudera-manager-isnt-opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56474423/cloudera-manager-isnt-opening/56477355#56477355) It's the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened the port 7180 on EC2 Instance Firewall but not on EC2 Security Group. By adding Port 7180 on EC2 Security Group now Cloudera manager working.

Comment: I have the same problem. How do You solve the problem - Which commands did You enter?

Comment: Command sequence is same as in question.       Please check if 7180 is added in security group or not.