# Cloudera Manager isn't opening

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have an VM: *cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.13.0-0-virtualbox*, run now.
But the Cloudera Manager's Page isn't being shown.
The message: 'Attempting to connect to Cloudera Manager...'
is being shown the all day.
[image]
How Can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudera manager has to be restarted separately in the quickstart VM. You can run the below command and see it works:

```
/home/cloudera/cloudera-manager --force --express
```